# Is this grammar valid: I have no idea what you need to make it work on a Mac

Tags: grammar

This statement here:

`I have no idea what you need to make it work on a Mac.`

seems off to me regarding grammar. Is it not supported to be `why` instead of `what`?

Comment: It’s definitely not correct unless you correct “an a Mac” to be “on a Mac” as it’s supposed to be.

Comment: That there is another typo I did not notice. Kudos to you sir/madam.

Comment: That's a different question altogether. With _what_, the infinitive _to make it work on a Mac_ is interpreted as ***in order** to make it work on a Mac* -- a purpose infinitive. So it's asking what is necessary to bring that off -- new compiler, new source code, different app altogether -- whereas _why_ asks for a reason to make it work on a Mac, instead of a resource search.

Comment: @JohnLawler you are right. Draken has pointed me to the two possible, and both correct intentions in the statement. I had read it as `why` and therefore placed myself in that box, and didn't realise the other meaning, which was the intended meaning as a matter of fact. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context, which you have not provided. 
If you are questioning the necessity of making something work on a Mac, then it should be written: I have no idea why you need to make it work on a Mac. 
If you are questioning what tools or methods are required to make something work on a Mac, then it should be written: I have no idea what you need to make it work on a Mac.

Comment: Jeez, its only making sense to me now. I absolutely missed the meaning in that statement. Wow hahaha, will mark this as correct answer after a few minutes. My actions seem to still be controlled. Cheers

Comment: Don't be too downhearted, @pnizzle: it is a bit like a [garden-path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence): if you misread "what" as "why", then it has a different parse until that fails, and you might easily miss the right parse, as you did.